# Xcode 6 Validate/Submit inactive

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode6, app-store

I'm trying to upload my first apple app and i've been not able to get further this point within last 7 days, so reaching out for help.

I do have app preset in itunesConnect and all the certificates available and am able to run app on my device, but when it comes time to create archive i can see it is building without errors and i can even see that .xcarchive file being created but neither Validate nor Submit buttons are available for me to click on.

Also when i click on that archive it says
Archive type: Generic Xcode Archive
and both version and identifier have Unspecified next to them.

Again, i've been trying to solve it for a week, and tried lots of stuff online as well as watching the course on pluralsight on deploing iOS apps to the apple store and had no luck figuring it out yet.

What am i missing?

Comment: can you please share screenshot..?

Comment: well we took a different approach.
We created a simple project and passed that point, so now are trying to add parts of this current project and see what is causing this issue. I think it has to do with 2 projects integrated with each other in 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your problem really is, but this is how i would solve it..

1) Create smaller project may be just 1 single page app and try to do what you want with it all the way to the appstore

2) once you got 1 to work add your project to this smaller project and see where your issues are..

Hope that helps!

Comment: That's exactly how i decided to approach it. The issue was with sub-project that wasn't mapped correctly..